# How to get list of available commands in Brackets?

Tags: javascript, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to add custom keyboard short-cut to my Brackets. Now my keymap contains the following overrides:

```
"overrides": {
    "Ctrl-S":"file.saveAll"
}
```

I want to add a short-cut for command described [here](https://github.com/yasinkuyu/brackets-tools/blob/master/lib/stringConvert.js#L430). As far as I found form Developer tools, CommandManager runs this command with ID `"insya-tools-string_uppercase"`. But when I tried to add line

```
"Ctrl-Shift-U": "insya-tools-string_uppercase"
```

I've got an error "You assigning shortcuts to nonexisting command". I've tried `"insya-tools.string_uppercase"` and all other combinations. But result is the same. So I think, that maybe there is no registered hmm.. another-type-of-id for this command. But since I sometimes want to add also other command short-cuts, I'm wondering if there is a way to get list of all available commands or something.

Answer (score 1):

There's an extension called [Display Shortcuts](https://github.com/redmunds/brackets-display-shortcuts) in the extension registry. Install it to then click `Help > Show Shortcuts`.

It'll then show you a list like this:
[image: Extension output]